# how to import the 3D model from Solidworks

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

as title
thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/240/how-to-import-the-3d-model-from-solidworks/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I recommend using the [Solidworks to URDF exporter](http://ros.org/wiki/sw_urdf_exporter). This will generate a urdf file that can be read into gazebo. See some of the [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#Building_a_Robot) for further info about gazebo models.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brawner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12/brawner/) on 2013-01-14**:
I approve of this message.